# WD Black NVMe SSD 2018 is not working under Linux / Ubuntu

Tags: ssd, nvme

I've bought a new Western Digital (WD) Black NVMe SSD 2018, but can't install Linux on it. System freezes. And the only live image that will run is Lubuntu 18.04.  Ubuntu and Mate live image (and Fedora 28) will freeze after 30 seconds or so.

Clevo n130wu, Intel 8550u, iGPU.

SSD is listed under /dev/nvme0, but `nvme list` will freeze the system.

If I boot with acpi=off the disk is not under /dev/nvme*

According to this [support page](https://support.wdc.com/knowledgebase/answer.aspx?ID=17144&s=) it should work under Linux, although I'm not sure if this relates to the 2018 model. Anandtech seems to have [tested it](https://www.anandtech.com/print/12543/the-western-digital-wd-black-3d-nand-ssd-review) with kernel 4.14.

*UPDATE*

SSD Dashboard utility is Windows only and doesn't run under wine.

Comment: Many users with other SSD have had to update firmware. Is yours the newest firmware? Are you booting in UEFI boot mode?

Comment: UEFI mode yes. Latest firmware, I suppose it's brand new but I don't how to check: nvme is not working.

Comment: Does Dashboard have update as an option? Seems to be Windows only for Dashboard. https://support.wdc.com/product.aspx?ID=1804&lang=en#WD_downloads

Comment: Buying a Window license for this problem is out of the question.

Comment: You can try booting with `acpiphp.disable=1` and if that doesn't work then with `pcie_aspm=off` as well. Does your laptop have a Kaby Lake processor? There might be an issue there too. Also what type of graphics are you using? That probably isn't effecting install but someone might have had experience with that in the past.

Comment: Unfortunately both options do not help.

Comment: I'm confirming this issue. See also: - [Fedora forum](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?318671-Unable-to-boot-from-live-F28-image-on-brand-new-laptop)
- [Red Hat Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1599042)
- [WD community](https://community.wd.com/t/linux-support-for-wd-black-nvme-2018/225446)

Comment: Check that the storage interface is AHCI and not RAID. Could this be the cause of your problem? Go to the BIOS and change storage interface to AHCI for your NVMe drive.

Comment: Same problem here. After updating my ASRock X470 Gaming-ITX/ac BIOS it would no longer boot. WDS500G2X0C-00L350 has firmware 101020WD. I ran SSD Dashboard and it showed no firmware update available. After downgrading the BIOS it boots okay now. Maybe it has something to do with the PinnaclePI-AM4 1.0.04 AGESA. I was also able to run kernel 4.14 in emergency mode with the new BIOS, but 4.16 on up did not work.